# Alternatives to JSON file credentials?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

My Java backend server has to upload files to the Google Cloud Storage (GCS).

Right now I just run

```java
public void store(MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException {

    Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

    storage.create(
            BlobInfo.newBuilder(
                    BUCKET_NAME,
                    Objects.requireNonNull(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()))
                    .build(),
            multipartFile.getBytes()
    );
}
```

Having set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$PROJECT_DIR$/project-1234-abcdefg.json` in my environment.

However, this makes things complicated for my deployment setup. I don't know how I would go about making this file available to my service.

Is there another way to get access to GCS for my service account?

---

### Background

I am deploying my server to Heroku as a compiled jar file and I don't know how to make the credentials available to my server during deployment.

Comment: Have a read at the following ... https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production

Use of an explicit file containing credentials is just one option.  Where is your "backend" server running?  Is it on a GCP Compute Engine?  If yes, then you can control the service account it runs as and give that service account sufficient GCS privileges.

Comment: @Kolban Yes, I've seen this. But my server is running on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Google Account to access to GCS, either personal or technical. Technical is a service account.

However, you have another solution, but not really easy to implement. I [wrote an article for securing serverless product with Cloud Endpoint with and API Key](https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1). Here your serverless solution can be Cloud Storage. But that implies that you call GCS with REST API and not with the java library, not very fun. That also implies additional cost for the hosting and the processing time of Cloud Endpoint.

*Note: you can improve the authorization from API Key to Firebase auth or something else if you prefer. Check the [Cloud Endpoint authentication capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method)*

*Note2: Google is working on another authentication mechanism but I don't know at which stage are the developments, and if it's plan for 2020. In any case, your constraint is known and addressed by Google*

Comment: Hi! I am already using a service account but this requires me to provide the json files with credentials somehow to the server on startup. The article you posted looks like my application would have to run on GAE?

Comment: No. You can use Cloud Endpoints as proxy: Your application call Cloud Endpoint with the authorization method that you want (an API Key if you want), Cloud Endpoint authenticate your Application, and call, with its own service account deployed on it, the target endpoint (here the Storage API). But that implies that you call the Storage API with REST request and not with the library, and to decrease your security level by using an API KEY.